# VBA alternative to xlToRight (without select/selection)

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me with an alternative to "`select`" and "`selection`" and "`End(xlToRight)`" - I want to use the value of the far-right cell (row 1) in the `If` statement below but without activating the sheet and selecting cells. Please advise, thanks.

```
d.Activate: Range("C1").Select: Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
If Selection <> DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1) Then
Debug.Print "add DATE"
d.Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1)
Else
Debug.Print "do not add DATE"
End If
```

Comment: Considering the syntax of *DateSerial* as `DateSerial([Year], [Month], [Day])`, did you find `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1)` too boring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming variable "d" is a reference to a sheet, you can retrieve the "far-right" cell by using `End(xlToLeft)`, starting from the last column on the sheet (`d.Columns.Count`) and store the range in a variable like so:

```
Dim myRange As Range
    
Set myRange = d.Cells(1, d.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
```

Then just use the variable in place of any select statements you're using:

```
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = d.Cells(1, d.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

If myRange <> DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1) Then
    Debug.Print "add DATE"
    myRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1)
Else
    Debug.Print "do not add DATE"
End If
```

Comment: It appears I misunderstood your original question. However after your edit, I think I understand what you're trying to avoid now and have updated my answer accordingly.

Let me know if this isn't what you were after